# Uniform Convergence "Switching Limits"

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

First off, I apologize for the bad wording; I am new to real analysis, and I have a few questions regarding uniform convergence.

(1)

We know that if $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly $\forall x \in E$,

$\lim_{x \to p} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to p} f_n(x)$.

Is there a particular name for this theorem?
$ $

(2)

If $\lim_{x \to p} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to p} f_n(x)$, does this imply uniform convergence; If we can 'switch around' limits, does this imply that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent?

If such a similar question/post exists, please feel free to redirect/criticize me. Thank you a lot for all the help.

Comment: The theorem is close to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition

Comment: In our textbook we called it *"Interchange of Limit Operations"* and even included an index entry "interchange of limit operations."  Nothing wrong with "switch" or even "switcheroo" if you are feeling frisky.  "Limit swapping" might sound bawdy.